# How to apply different styles to bootstrap dropdown (when mobile view and when pc view)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to style my `top menu` navigation where `Language` link is only as wide as the link requires (same for `dropdown background`), but when it gets resized to fit mobilde devices, the drop downs should be 100% in width, here's how far I have got [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UqTYf/)
as you can see I haven't been able to do either of the two requirements ...

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/USEwuvo/1/edit

[image]
[image]

HTML Needs some repair (didn't put in the brand since yours was missing):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top-nav"> <span class="sr-only">Navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
  </div>
  <!-- navbar header --> 
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="top-nav">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li> <a href="#" class="treneri"> Trainers </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="pasakums"> Event </a> </li>
    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tickets <b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Buy tickets here</a> </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown lang"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">LAT <b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu language">
      <li><a href="#">RUS</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">ENG</a> </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
 </div>  <!-- /.container -->

</nav>
```

**Then the CSS**

```
.container {width:auto}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  
  .nav.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu.language  {
    min-width:0px!important;
  }

}/* end min-width for language */
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't thought of that :)